# import jcc, DLL load failed

Tags: python, jcc

I build JCC 2.12. Next, I tried to import jcc but I get this error message:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

First I think about jvm.dll, and I put direct link to jcc\windows.py

> def add_jvm_dll_directory_to_path():
>
> ```
> path = os.environ['Path'].split(os.pathsep)
> dll_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_30\\jre\\bin\\server'
> path.append(dll_path)
> os.environ['Path'] = os.pathsep.join(path)
> return True
>
> raise ValueError, "jvm.dll could not be found"
> ```

Second. I try to add C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\JCC-2.11-py2.7-win32.egg to the PATH

Finally, I try another pre-builded jcc from http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/pylucene-extra and get the same error.

Which library is needed?

Comment: You could try using Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the resultant (pyd?) file to see what you are missing.

Comment: Hm, manual adding of libraries path don't help.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same question.

try add jvm.dll's directory to envirement varible Path.

follow is my jvm.dll directory.

C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\bin\client

Comment: Your solution works! This helps it find the dll. Thanks :)